# Trying to build an Ionic 4 app for Android but gradle, paths and variables aren't found even though I've already set them

Tags: android, ionic-framework, gradle, angular7, ionic4

everyone. I want to build an app for one of my clients. It's the first time I develop an app on Ionic 4 and at the time of building the apk, I couldn't do it.

I checked all the errors that the console prompted to me. At first, it seemed to be moving on, however, at a moment, the console prompted the following:

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Cris/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studio
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
cordova build android --release exited with exit code 1.
```

I have already done a research about this topic, and even though there are similar questions here on this website, I couldn't find any answer that solved my problem.

I have already defined the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT, the ANDROID_HOME and GRADLE_HOME. I checked all of those dirs to see if they worked, and they did so. I have already downloaded and set up the JDK variable and path as well.

I have installed Android Studio with the version of sdk API that I need for this development. Also, when I researched about gradle, I installed it with npm and manually (without counting the time it got installed automatically with Android Studio). HOWEVER!!! The console tells that gradle isn't installed, that Android paths aren't set or that they are deprecated (both options, actually), and that I have to do what I have already done several times.

Here I let you see the variables set:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Cris/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export GRADLE_HOME=/Users/Cris/Library/Gradle.0/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin
```

Do you guys have any idea of how to proceed? Thank you before hand

Answer (score 0):

GRADLE_HOME should be the root folder of the `<gradle installation folder>`, currently its pointing to `<gradle installation folder>/bin` it should look like following

```
export GRADLE_HOME=/Users/Cris/Library/Gradle.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm going to try it out. However, what about the other not found paths of Android?

Comment: It seems correct you can verify it by executing java -version and gradle -version. If it's giving proper value then you are good to go.

Comment: it didn't work at all. I mean, the console errors say practically the same as if I didn't install anything and as if I didn't set up the paths (what I did, both)

Comment: it says "command not found" when I run "gradle -version". But gradle folder is in my pc and installed globally with npm

Comment: Follow the instruction same as mentioned in this link(https://gradle.org/install/)

Comment: I did just as you said. I installed gradle, unzipped it on the corresponding folder, updated the $GRADLE_HOME path, but...everythng is the same as before. Can you tell me if creating the path "$GRADLE_HOME" is actually right? is it that name that it has to have? or is there anything else that I didn't consider before? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have already overcame the problem with the following instructions:

- When you want to build your app for Android with Ionic 4 on MAC, install Java (JDK), install Android Studio, install the API version you want to work with, install Homebrew (on its website there is a so easy-to-follow guide to install it) and install Gradle by writing the following command:

  **brew install gradle**
- Then, write the following command and copy the route of the gradle directory:

  **brew info gradle**
- Go to [Ionic Framework Developer Resources for MAC](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/platform-setup/mac-setup.html)
- And follow the instructions to set up the paths. Don't forget to check if the example paths work just fine on your computer by doing it as the following example:

  **ls /Users/your-user/Library/gradle-5.4**

If the "echo" of that line says that the directory exists, then it's okay and you must set that path the way it is. If the directory doesn't exists (as it'll happen in the case of the $GRADLE_HOME's path, you should paste the route that you copied some steps ago.

- To corroborate that those paths exist on your MAC, besids saving them on your MAC's ~/.bash_profile, enter them one by one (exporting the variable and exporting its path) inside the MAC's terminal.
- Then, as one of the last steps (I'm not going to describe how to sign your app, because it's explained on the link above), write on a console opened inside your project the following line:

  **sudo ionic cordova build android --prod**

  It's going to build your app for production, which releases you from signing your app in order to install it on your mobile device

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

If you want to sign your app, you should run the following command before signing it (it replaces the last command I wrote above):

```
sudo ionic cordova build --release android
```

You can find more information about releasing your app without a signed key and how to sign it on this website's section:

[Publishing Your App - Ionic Framework](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html)

Thank you for checking this answer out! :D